# PHP Help Using ACF Pro to Load/Enqueue CSS Stylesheet on WordPress Archives, Pages, and Posts

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, elementor, acfpro

I have no experience with PHP. I am using ACF select fields to give my client the option of choosing a stylesheet at the individual page, post, and archive level. Just for reference, the fields are singular_css, portfolio_css, and careers_css, depending on the content type, and share these dropdown values:

```
/wp-content/themes/hello-theme-child-master/custom-css/white.css : White
/wp-content/themes/hello-theme-child-master/custom-css/black.css : Black
/wp-content/themes/hello-theme-child-master/custom-css/blue.css : Blue
/wp-content/themes/hello-theme-child-master/custom-css/tan.css : Tan
/wp-content/themes/hello-theme-child-master/custom-css/gray.css : Gray
```

This script in the functions.php seems to work as expected to control the stylesheet that gets loaded on singular Posts/Pages, but doesn't allow them to choose a stylesheet for custom post type archives:

```
/** Insert Dynamic Stylesheet Into <Head> using ACF Field **/
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_head_script' );
function add_head_script() { ?>

<?php 
$singular_css = get_field('singular_css');
if( $singular_css ): ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo esc_url( $singular_css ); ?>">
<?php endif; ?>

<?php }
```

Since I wasn't able to control the stylesheet on custom post archives the same way, I've created options pages for them:

```
/** Creates ACF Options Pages **/
if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {
    
    acf_add_options_sub_page(array(
        'page_title'    => 'Portfolio Style',
        'menu_title'    => 'Portfolio Style',
        'parent_slug'   => 'edit.php?post_type=portfolio',
        'capability'    => 'manage_options'
    ));
    
    acf_add_options_sub_page(array(
        'page_title'    => 'Careers Style',
        'menu_title'    => 'Careers Style',
        'parent_slug'   => 'edit.php?post_type=careers',
        'capability'    => 'manage_options'
    ));
    
}
```

And tried to enqueue the stylesheets instead, but something isn't working:

```
/** Enqueue Dynamic Stylesheet using ACF Field **/
function dynamic_style() {
    $singular_css = get_field('singular_css');
    $portfolio_css = get_field('portfolio_css', 'option');
    $careers_css = get_field('careers_css', 'option');

    if (is_singular()) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'singular_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). $singular_css );
    }
    elseif (is_post_type_archive('portfolio')) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'portfolio_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). $portfolio_css );
    }
    elseif (is_post_type_archive('careers')) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'careers_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). $careers_css );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dynamic_style' );
```

I also tried writing it this way, but it still doesn't work:

```
/** Enqueue Dynamic Stylesheet using ACF Field **/
function singular_style() {
    $singular_css = get_field('singular_css');
    if (is_singular()) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'singular_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). $singular_css );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'singular_style' );
    
function portfolio_style() {
    $portfolio_css = get_field('portfolio_css', 'option');
    if (is_post_type_archive('portfolio')) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'portfolio_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). $portfolio_css );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'portfolio_style' );  
    
function careers_style() {
    $careers_css = get_field('careers_css', 'option');  
    if (is_post_type_archive('careers')) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'careers_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). $careers_css );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'careers_style' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to change the dropdown value to

```
  /custom-css/white.css : White
    /custom-css/black.css : Black
    /custom-css/blue.css : Blue
    /custom-css/tan.css : Tan
    /custom-css/gray.css : Gray
```

And then add the following code on functions.php file

```
 function dynamic_style()
    {
        if (is_singular()) {
            global $post;
            $cog_stylesheet = get_field('cog_background_color', $post->ID);
            wp_enqueue_style('singular_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . $cog_stylesheet);
        }else {

    global $post;
    $post_type = get_current_post_types($post);

    if ($post_type == 'portfolio') {
        $portfolio_css = get_field('portfolio_css', 'option');
        wp_enqueue_style('portfolio_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . $portfolio_css);
    } elseif ($post_type == 'careers') {
        $careers_css = get_field('careers_css', 'option');
        wp_enqueue_style('careers_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . $careers_css);
    } 
}
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dynamic_style');
```

However, if you still want to use the current dropdown value add the following code on the functions.php file to

```
function dynamic_style()
{
    if (is_singular()) {
        global $post;
        $cog_stylesheet = get_field('cog_background_color', $post->ID);
        wp_enqueue_style('singular_css', home_url() . $cog_stylesheet);
    } else {

    global $post;
    $post_type = get_current_post_types($post);

    if ($post_type == 'portfolio') {
        $portfolio_css = get_field('portfolio_css', 'option');
        wp_enqueue_style('portfolio_css', home_url() . $portfolio_css);
    } elseif ($post_type == 'careers') {
        $careers_css = get_field('careers_css', 'option');
        wp_enqueue_style('careers_css', home_url() . $careers_css);
    } 
}
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dynamic_style');
```

And add the following code on functions.php so that we can get post_type on archive page

```
function get_current_post_types($object = null)
{

    // if a numeric value passed, assume it is a post ID
    if (($object) && (is_numeric($object))) {
        $object = get_post($object);
    }
    // if an object is passed, assume to be a post object
    if (($object) && (is_object($object))) {
        return get_post_type($object);
    }

    // standard single post type checks
    if (is_404()) {
        return '';
    }
    // update: removed this check, handled by is_singular
    // if (is_single()) {return 'post';}
    if (is_page()) {
        return 'page';
    }
    if (is_attachment()) {
        return 'attachment';
    }
    if (is_singular()) {
        return get_post_type();
    }

    // if a custom query object was not passed, use $wp_query global
    if ((!$object) || (!is_object($object))) {
        global $wp_query;
        $object = $wp_query;
    }
    if (!is_object($object)) {
        return '';
    } // should not fail

    // if the post_type query var has been explicitly set
    // (or implicitly set on the cpt via a has_archive redirect)
    // ie. this is true for is_post_type_archive at least
    // $vqueriedposttype = get_query_var('post_type'); // $wp_query only
    if (property_exists($object, 'query_vars')) {
        $posttype = $object->query_vars['post_type'];
        if ($posttype) {
            return $posttype;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Bijay, I modified my dropdown values as you recommended and added the first code snippet you provided (slightly modified to reflect some naming changes to the singular field from my original post you found on Facebook) but it didn't work as expected.

Comment: I think color and background-color styles in other Elementor css files are overriding it. Is there a way to change the load order so it's css values render instead of the Elementor stylesheet's?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Bijay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2045349/bijay-yadav)! You've been a huge help. Just to recap for others, here are the steps I took:

I registered these options pages:

```
/** Creates ACF Options Pages **/
if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {
    
    acf_add_options_sub_page(array(
        'page_title'    => 'Posts Style',
        'menu_title'    => 'Posts Stylesheet',
        'parent_slug'   => 'edit.php',
        'capability'    => 'manage_options'
    ));
    
    acf_add_options_sub_page(array(
        'page_title'    => 'Portfolio Style',
        'menu_title'    => 'Portfolio Stylesheet',
        'parent_slug'   => 'edit.php?post_type=portfolio',
        'capability'    => 'manage_options'
    ));
    
    acf_add_options_sub_page(array(
        'page_title'    => 'Careers Style',
        'menu_title'    => 'Careers Stylesheet',
        'parent_slug'   => 'edit.php?post_type=careers',
        'capability'    => 'manage_options'
    ));
    
}
```

I created my ACF select fields:

- singular_css
- articles_css
- portfolio_css
- careers_css

And they all share these dropdown values:

- /custom-css/white.css : White
- /custom-css/black.css : Black
- /custom-css/blue.css : Blue
- /custom-css/tan.css : Tan
- /custom-css/gray.css : Gray

This code in the functions.php file works:

```
/** Enqueue Dynamic Stylesheet using ACF Field **/
function dynamic_style()
{
    if (is_singular()) {
        global $post;
        $singular_css = get_field('singular_css', $post->ID);
        wp_enqueue_style('singular_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). $singular_css);
    } elseif (is_home()) {
        $articles_css = get_field('articles_css', 'option');
        wp_enqueue_style('articles_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). $articles_css);
    } elseif (is_post_type_archive('portfolio')) {
        $portfolio_css = get_field('portfolio_css', 'option');
        wp_enqueue_style('portfolio_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). $portfolio_css);
    } elseif (is_post_type_archive('careers')) {
        $careers_css = get_field('careers_css', 'option');
        wp_enqueue_style('careers_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). $careers_css);
    } elseif (is_404()) {
        wp_enqueue_style('white_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/custom-css/white.css');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dynamic_style', 99);
```